# Anonymous access icon not visible sharepoint 2013

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to make my sharepoint app hosted on sharepoint 2013 visible from anonymous users, but the anonymous access button is missing....anyone know how to make it visible?

[image]

Thank you
Mario

Comment: Hello you resolve this problem? I have the same problem with sharepoint 2013, helpme please.

Answer (score 1):

You should open the central administration -> web application settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579415(v=office.15).aspx#Configuring